# JSON to Pandas dataframe conversion

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I have trouble with conversion of JSON formatted data to Pandas dataframe. My JSON data looks like this and is stored in the variable active_assets -

```
Asset({   'class': 'us_equity',
    'easy_to_borrow': True,
    'exchange': 'NYSE',
    'id': '879ac630-107f-43ce-a01d-1fd9da89453c',
    'marginable': True,
    'name': 'Zymeworks Inc.',
    'shortable': True,
    'status': 'active',
    'symbol': 'ZYME',
    'tradable': True}), Asset({   'class': 'us_equity',
    'easy_to_borrow': False,
    'exchange': 'NASDAQ',
    'id': 'a838c0cf-0008-432e-8882-feee5a6ef7cd',
    'marginable': True,
    'name': 'Zynerba Pharmaceuticals, Inc. Common Stock',
    'shortable': False,
    'status': 'active',
    'symbol': 'ZYNE',
    'tradable': True}), Asset({   'class': 'us_equity',
    'easy_to_borrow': True,
    'exchange': 'NASDAQ',
    'id': '52eed246-61b0-4e82-95a9-1d23906b752e',
    'marginable': True,
    'name': 'Zynex, Inc. Common Stock',
    'shortable': True,
    'status': 'active',
    'symbol': 'ZYXI',
    'tradable': True})

active_assets = api.list_assets(status='active',asset_class='us_equity')
df_dict = [{'SYMBL':i['symbol'], 'NAME':i['name'],'Shortable':i['shortable']} for i in active_assets['Asset']]
extracted_df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
```

When i run this code I get the following error? Any help is appreciated.

```
  File "D:\Trading-Scripts\Scan-alpaca.py", line 32, in <module>
    df_dict = [{'SYMBL':i['symbol'], 'NAME':i['name'],'Shortable':i['shortable']} for i in active_assets['Asset']]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Apparently `i` is a list. You may want to check its type.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over a dictionary in your dictionary comprehension. Try to have i equal to your json object.

You can also try to use the read_json method from pandas.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html